# SMTP Gateway/Relay in Cloud with Local SMTP Server behind DHCP

Tags: server, vpn, postfix, aws, smtp

I am having some difficulty figuring out how to setup a mail server in AWS to act as the front-end to another mail server on my local network. Since I am behind a dynamic IP address (no options for Static IP's from my ISP), I can't directly host the server on my local network, so to get around this issue I was thinking about setting up a VPN tunnel between the two servers, and somehow getting the local server to relay any emails destined to the world, to the AWS server, while keeping anything internal on the internal server.

From my research and understanding, this indicates that I will need to setup the local server as an "Internet Site with Smarthost" in Postfix, and tell it to relay the emails to the AWS server through the VPN tunnel (directly specifying the VPN IP address of the AWS server in the postfix config, correct?). This is where my confusion starts. I have found tutorials for setting up postfix to send email with an external SMTP server, which matches my goal, however all those tutorials are using other external SMTP servers such as Gmail.

How should I be configuring the AWS server? Just set it up as a regular mail server in Postfix similar to my current MailInABox instance, and then set the local server to use it as the external SMTP server like the tutorials show for using Gmail? Are there any specific setup I would have to do on both servers to get multiple users to work correctly, or is there something I'm just not getting that would just pass everything back to the local server and only use the AWS server for external access.

EDIT: It occurred to me that i might need to clarify my end goal a little better. I am wanting my emails to be stored internally on the local server and not on the AWS server. To have internet-bound emails to be passed from the internal server to the AWS server, and to have emails that hit the AWS server to be passed to the local server.